# Парсинг математических выражений

Tags: математика, php, синтаксический-анализ

Помогите написать алгоритм, загвоздка в том, что не получается написать нормальный парсинг для скобок, к примеру дана функция вида (((A+B)*C)-(A*(B+C))), нужен алгоритм, который будет грамотно понимать порядок выполнения операций, чтобы вначале выполнялось сложение,внутри скобок, потом умножение, а потом уже вычитание... мне нужен лишь алгоритм, в виде блок схемы, или же на код на PHP

Comment: [вас от гугля отключили ?](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: вы думаете я не искал?  я не нашел ничего, прежде чем сюда писать, я наверное все-таки искал!  во всяком случае мне не понятен язык C++  на котором все пишут этот парсер, я искал чисто алгоритм, и не нашел!

Comment: [тут тоже все ссылки c++](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9+php) ? в предыдущей теме уже говорили волшебное слово "обратная польская нотация" вот если вы ее не поймете, то не получится у вас парсить математику.

Answer (score 1):

Да валом же алгоритмов в гугле.

Пост на [Habrahabr.ru](http://habrahabr.ru/post/50196/)